# Jupyter Notebook: check the hdfs directory content

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am using the Jupyter Notebook, and here is one of the path I have used:

```
my_df = sqlContext.read.parquet('hdfs://myPath/user/hive/warehouse/myDB.db/myTable/**')
```

Since I want to check what's under `hdfs://myPath/user/hive/warehouse`

I did:

```
!ls hdfs://myPath/user/hive/warehouse
```

Then I got errors:

```
ls: cannot access hdfs://myPath/user/hive/warehouse: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing anything? What's the proper way for viewing a directory content from the Jupyter Notebook? Thanks!

Comment: how about `import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs  >>>  hdfs.ls("...path...")`

Comment: Try with **three** slashes -- the full syntax is `hdfs://namenode/some/path` and can be abbreviated as `hdfs:///some/path`  or even `/some/path` (using the "defaultFS" property from `core-site.xml`). Some tools tolerate the two-slash form just like Google Search tolerates typos, because, you know, people are illiterate. But some tools have a more rigid validation approach.

Comment: Also use the **proper Command-Line Interface (CLI)**: `ls` only knows about the local Linux filesystem; `hdfs dfs -ls` will reach into HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Please attempt below command and it should work

```
!hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
```